# Dimension of the image of kernel of $A$ if $A^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a nonzero $3\times 3$ matrix with $A^2=0$. What is the $\dim Im(A)$ and $\dim\ker(A)$?

I know $$\dim Im(A) + \dim\ker(A) = 3$$

but I don't know which is which.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Here is a [Mathjax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}w \in Im (A) \implies  A v = w  &\implies  0 =  A(Av) = A w \\&\implies  w \in \ker A \implies Im A \subset \ker A \\&\implies\dim Im A \leq \dim \ker A\end{align}$$

You take it from here?

Comment: Ahh... It took me a while to get it, but it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that since $A^2=0$ then:

$A$ is nilpotent so the only eigenvalue is $0$, with multiplicity 3.

$A$ has nilpotency index $2$, so $A$ is similar to the Jordan matrix 
$$J=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 &1 &  \\
0 &0  & 0 \\
& &0   \\         
\end{bmatrix} $$

Then we have $dim(kerA)=dim(kerJ)=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't studied eigenvectors and eigenvalues and that stuff yet.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron Maroja pointed out $\dim Im A \leq \dim \ker A$.

$2\dim Im A \leq \dim Im A + \dim ker A=3$ implies $\dim Im A \leq 1.5$. $\dim Im A$ is not $0$ as A is non-zero. Thus $\dim Im A=1$ and $\dim ker A=2$.

Comment: I get this, but how is $dimImA<=dimkerA$?